# C++/CLI Pragma managed

Tags: c++-cli

I am trying to do a calculator with GUI in c++. For that I choose CLR. And I have to use asembly for counting.

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    int x = 3; // this function is inside class
    x = foo(x);
    setTextOnLabel2(x);
}

private: System::Void textBox1_TextChanged(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
}
private: System::Void label1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
}

public: void setTextOnLabel2(int x) {
    System::String^ xString = System::Convert::ToString(x);
    this->label2->Text = xString;
}
};


#pragma managed(push, off)
int foo(int x)
{
  _asm {
    mov eax, 4
    mov x, 4
}
return x;
}
 #pragma managed(pop)

}
```

My problem is that I can't write asembly code directly in window form class. I have to do it from outside of class because I have to use #pragma managed. And I have big problem with this because I can't create another class because #pragma managed can only be used in global or namespace scope. So i can write function with asmebly but I don't know how to refer to it.

Comment: C++ uses a single-pass compilation model.  So you have to do the standard C++ dance, declaration of the Click event handler in the .h file, definition in the .cpp file.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was a really good idea. Now it's working :)